# How to make new canvases on button click in Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I have these buttons: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc90A.png
Everytime I click on each button I want to make a new canvas with +1 z-index.
I do not know how to make and use dynamic variables.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp, `element.style.zIndex=i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let canvas = createElement('canvas')
canvas.style.height = height
canvas.style.width = width
canvas.style.zIndex = 1
document.body.append(canvas)
```

Run the following code with different height and width on each respective button. I have not tested this, but it should work